# Disease predicting software for small molecules

Tags: cheminformatics

Can anyone please help me in finding softwares for predicting diseases from small molecules?

Comment: Please clarify: do you mean "list all known associated diseases for molecule X" or "predict all possible diseases for molecule X, including known ones"?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean predicting health effects/toxicity of a given chemical? I haven't seen such software and I doubt it exists. Much easier problem (predict optimal synthetic route to compound X remains unsolved.

By hand your best way is to check toxicity of related compounds. A program that can predict health effects of compounds will revolutionize drug design (and cause job loss for 99% of RnD chemists in pharma).